# DB2 sp_rename equivalent

Tags: db2

Is there a DB2 v9.1 equivalent for sp_rename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the object.

For tables and indexes, you can use the [RENAME](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000980.htm) sql statement.

If you want to rename a column, you can use [ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000888.htm).

For other objects, you probably have to drop and recreate it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: can i rename an sp or do i have to do a drop - create??

Comment: You have to do drop/create...alter procedure doesn't allow rename.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0008168.htm

Comment: Thanks Michael. I guess sp_rename in SQLServer would internally do the same. Drop and recreate.